# Measure Page Load Times in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

We are wanting to monitor our Blazor web pages to get an idea of page load times.
We are using client based Blazor.
I know that this can be done with Google Analytics and Raygun but am looking for something more in C# or Javascript.
I was hoping for something like starting a stopwatch on a begin event and stopping it on a loaded event, but this doesn't seem possible with Blazor.
I should also add that this is for an authenticated web app as I did consider having a separate 'monitoring' app that just ping'd the website periodically and measure the start and end request.

Answer (score 0):

```
@page "/Test"
//bind timer containing time in a string and display as a label
<label>@timer.time</label>
@code{
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
     Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
     timer.Start();
     //your code
     timer.Stop();
   }
}
```

Comment: That just measures time of execution of OnInitializedAsync